# Is it OK to retag from akka-persistence to akka.net-persistence?

Tags: discussion, tags

I found the following suggested edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20943569

It wants to replace:
[akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka) [akka.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka.net) [akka-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka-persistence)

with:
[akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka) [akka.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka.net) [akka.net-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka.net-persistence)

**Is that a good edit or not?**

There are no description for the tag [akka.net-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka.net-persistence) and only 23 questions compared to the 227 questions of [akka-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka-persistence). I am not familiar with akka / akka.net, but I feel there is some redundancy in those tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[akka.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka.net) seems to be a .NET port of [akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka).

Likewise, I'd assume [akka.net-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka.net-persistence) is a .NET port of [akka-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka-persistence).

Considering the code in the question looks like C#, changing the tag to the .NET variant seems like a good idea.

Comment: As a recent user of [tag:akka.net], the noise caused by [tag:akka] in my searches has proved irritating. Anything that differentiates is a good thing.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  I'm also a user of akka.net, and very often the answers are the same for both akka and akka.net, but since there's so much more activity for akka, you may not find them if you scope to akka.net.   I think it's more likely a case-by-case decision, based on whether the question is specific to the .net implementation.  Since the original question is about actor lifecycle, which is largely similar between the two, I might leave it as [tag:akka-persistence].

Answer (score 3):

Akka is the original product, available for Java and Scala. Akka.NET is the .NET port.

For some conceptual questions it may make sense to use both `[akka-*]` and `[akka.net-*]` tags, but usually a question should only use one of them.